# C#: Custom event invocation with last minute check to see if the subscriber really still is subscribing?

Tags: c#, events, method-invocation

I have a setup where two instances (A, B) is listening on a event on a third instance (C). A has also a reference to B.

When the event is fired on C, A receives it first and then directly disposes B (by design). In the dispose-method, B removes its listener on the event on C (-=). What happens next is that B still receives the callback from C, even though B has unsubscribed the event on C.

I guess this is expected since the invocation-list probably is built only once the event fires (when both listeners still exist) and is not rebuilt even though one instance happen to unsubscribe during the invocation-loop.

My question is why there isnt a secondary check before the event is raised, if the object is really still subscribing to the event or not? I guess this is bad for perfomance and its a very uncommon scenario. But if I want to implement this behaviour myself?

I've tried something like this but I'm not sure if this is all that's required (It seem to work though). How does the invocation-loop look like internally in C#?

```
  foreach(var e in Test.GetInvocationList())
  {
    if (!Test.GetInvocationList().Contains(e)) continue;

    e.DynamicInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
```

Comment: Dont even try. An event is a special type of a delegate which is an immutable value type. It's difficult but not impossible to remove one subscriber from an event while triggering that event. Next to that, there is no guaranteed order in which subscribers should be notified. The real problem ofcourse comes with the philosophy of events. you are simply trying to abuse a system. Rather set a property on the B instance.

Comment: But how does it work internally and why isnt this a built in feature in som way? I mean if a event is unsubscribed before the eventhandler is invoked, I obviously don't want it to be invoked. It's almost like a bug to me.

Comment: No its not. A delegate is a value type and copies by value. Invoking an event simply produces code that gets a copy of the current delegate and invokes each participant. Modifying the original delegate won't change the copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean way via the invocation list, etc.

The easiest is to have B set an old-fashioned bool flag when it deregisters and do a top-level if(unregistered==true) return; in the event handler.